# Why NuGet Package manager stopped

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I am trying to install **SignalR.Client**.  [image]. But it stop like that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly related to programming.

Comment: Why? I cannot install  any package. There must be a way solve this error.